# How can I search for all files on my harddisk in windows 7 within a certain timeframe?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I would like to show **all files** on my harddrive that were modified in september 2013. And, I would like to **exclude** a certain folder with millions of java files.

The windows search function in th top right of the explorer doesent offer me such precice options.

I used *Total Commander* where I selected the Harddrive D: and pressed *CTRL + b* to **unfold all folders**. Then I sort by date and scroll to the desired timeframe. This works, but it is **really slow** (and it doesent show me the folders on D: only files are sown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows search has advanced options, the documentation is just has to be hunted for.

Typing in the search box **-folder:(C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\chart graphing)** is an exclusion due to the **-** symbol.

**datemodified:‎9/‎1/‎2013 .. ‎9/‎30/‎2013**

**datemodified:‎9/‎1/‎2013 .. ‎9/‎30/‎2013 -folder:(c:\windows\temp) folder:(c:,d:,e:)**

Yes all of that has to be typed in the tiny **Windows Search** box.

Comment: thanks to you, I found a tutorial here: http://www.howtogeek.com/73065/learn-the-advanced-search-operators-in-windows-7/

Comment: @bensch even that article, **while helpfull** is incomplete.  These are also valid.  **cameramake:sony cameramodel:DSC-R1 -folder:(c:\x)**